# Python list: Copy single list to 2D list

Tags: python, list

how can i copy a single dimensional list to a two dimensional list?

```
import copy
dataList=[1,2,3,4,5]
multiList=([[],[],[],[],[]])

multiList = copy.deepcopy(dataList)
print(multiList[0][0])
```

Comment: Why do you create `multiList=([[],[],[],[],[]])` and then immediately discard it? What do you want `multiList` to contain?

Comment: Please show your expected result.  What should it print? What does `multiList` look like after the copy?

Comment: I suspect that you want `multiList` to contain `[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]`, but you **need** to tell us that. Also, do you want to mutate the existing `multiList` or is it ok to create a fresh 2D list? If you don't clarify these points, then it's likely that the question will be put on hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to put your `dataList` into `multiList[0][0]` then no need to use deepcopy. Just do this: `multiList[0][0] = dataList`

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy
dataList=[1,2,3,4,5]
multiList=([[],[],[],[],[]])

multiList[0] = copy.deepcopy(dataList) 


dataList[0] = 7 
print dataList
print(multiList)
```

Its trivial - I suggest to delete the question :)

Output:

```
 [7, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [], [], [], []]
```